# The ball is not detecting the paddle in pygame and I can't figure out why

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making Pong game in pygame but it isn't complete yet. The names of variables, classes and other things in the code are in portuguese but I think that's easy to know what wich one does. The code makes two paddles and one ball that bounces when hits the upper and lower limits of the game window. It should also bouce when it hits the paddles but that's not happening. It just gets out of the window ignoring the paddle. I don't get any error message.

Complete code:

```
import pygame,sys,os
import random
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

janela=pygame.display.set_mode((800, 500),0,32)
pygame.display.set_caption("Pong!")
superficie=pygame.display.get_surface()

clock=pygame.time.Clock()

fundoFicheiro=os.path.join("Imagens","fundo2.png")
fundoImagem=pygame.image.load(fundoFicheiro).convert()
fundoFinal=pygame.transform.smoothscale(fundoImagem,(superficie.get_width(),superficie.get_height()))

barraFicheiro=os.path.join("Imagens","barra.png")
barraImagem=pygame.image.load(barraFicheiro).convert_alpha()

bolaFicheiro=os.path.join("Imagens","bola.png")
bolaImagem=pygame.image.load(bolaFicheiro).convert_alpha()


def imprimirBarra(x,y):
        janela.blit(barraImagem,(x,y)) 



class barra():
    y=1
    x=1
    velocidade=1
    def subir(self):
        self.y-=self.velocidade
    def descer(self):
        self.y+=self.velocidade
    def parar(self):
        self.velocidade=0
    def comecar(self):
        self.velocidade=5
    def check(self):
        if self.y<20:
            self.y=20
        elif self.y>superficie.get_height()-barraImagem.get_height()-20:
            self.y=superficie.get_height()-barraImagem.get_height()-20     



barra1=barra()
barra1.x=5
barra1.y=superficie.get_height()/2-barraImagem.get_height()/2
barra2=barra()
barra2.x=superficie.get_width()-(barraImagem.get_width()+5)
barra2.y=superficie.get_height()/2-barraImagem.get_height()/2


def interface():
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type==KEYDOWN:
            if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_UP]:              
                barra2.comecar()
                barra2.check()
                barra2.subir()
            elif pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_DOWN]:
                barra2.comecar()
                barra2.check()
                barra2.descer()
            if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_w]:
                barra1.comecar()
                barra1.check()
                barra1.subir()
            elif pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_s]:
                barra1.comecar()
                barra1.check()
                barra1.descer()  
        if event.type==KEYUP:
            if event.type==K_UP:
                barra2.parar()
            elif event.type==K_DOWN:
                barra2.parar()
            elif event.type==K_w:
                barra1.parar()
            elif event.type==K_s:
                    barra1.parar()

class bola():
    y=1
    x=1
    velocidadeX=1
    velocidadeY=1
    mover="a"
    ultimaPosX=1
    ultimaPosY=1
    pontuacao1=0
    pontuacao2=0
    def subirDireita(self):
        self.x+=self.velocidadeX
        self.y-=self.velocidadeY
    def subirEsquerda(self):
        self.x-=self.velocidadeX
        self.y-=self.velocidadeY
    def descerDireita(self):
        self.x+=self.velocidadeX
        self.y+=self.velocidadeY
    def descerEsquerda(self):
        self.x-=self.velocidadeX
        self.y+=self.velocidadeY
    def colisao(self):
        lista1=range(barra1.y,barra1.y+barraImagem.get_height()+1)
        lista2=range(barra2.y,barra2.y+barraImagem.get_height()+1)
        if self.y<1 and self.x<self.ultimaPosX:
            self.velocidadeY=random.uniform(self.velocidadeX-0.5,self.velocidadeX+3.1)
            self.ultimaPosX=self.x
            self.ultimaPosY=self.y
            self.mover="descerEsquerda"  
        elif self.y<1 and self.x>self.ultimaPosX:
            self.velocidadeY=random.uniform(self.velocidadeX-0.5,self.velocidadeX+3.1)
            self.ultimaPosX=self.x
            self.ultimaPosY=self.y
            self.mover="descerDireita"    
        elif self.y>superficie.get_height()-bolaImagem.get_height()-1 and self.x>self.ultimaPosX:
            self.velocidadeY=random.uniform(self.velocidadeX-0.5,self.velocidadeX+3.1)
            self.ultimaPosX=self.x
            self.ultimaPosY=self.y
            self.mover="subirDireita"
        elif self.y>superficie.get_height()-bolaImagem.get_height()-1 and self.x<self.ultimaPosX:
            self.velocidadeY=random.uniform(self.velocidadeX-0.8,self.velocidadeX+3.1)
            self.ultimaPosX=self.x
            self.ultimaPosY=self.y
            self.mover="subirEsquerda"
        elif self.x<5+barraImagem.get_width()-1 and self.y>self.ultimaPosY and self.y in lista1:
            self.ultimaPosX=self.x
            self.ultimaPosY=self.y
            self.mover="descerDireita" 
        elif self.x<5+barraImagem.get_width()-1 and self.y<self.ultimaPosY and self.y in lista1:
            self.ultimaPosX=self.x
            self.ultimaPosY=self.y
            self.mover="subirDireita" 
        elif self.x>superficie.get_width()-5-barraImagem.get_width()-bolaImagem.get_width()-1 and self.y<self.ultimaPosY and self.y in lista2:
            self.ultimaPosX=self.x
            self.ultimaPosY=self.y
            self.mover="subirEsquerda"
        elif self.x>superficie.get_width()-5-barraImagem.get_width()-bolaImagem.get_width()-1 and self.y>self.ultimaPosY and self.y in lista2:
            self.ultimaPosX=self.x
            self.ultimaPosY=self.y
            self.mover="descerEsquerda"
        elif self.x<0-bolaImagem.get_width():
            self.pontuacao1+=1
            self.comecar()
        elif self.x>superficie.get_width():
            self.pontuacao2+=1
            self.comecar()    
    def font1(self):
        font=pygame.font.Font(None,100)
        text=font.render(str(self.pontuacao1),1,(255,255,255))
        textPos=text.get_rect(right=(superficie.get_width()/2+superficie.get_width()/4),y=(superficie.get_height()-superficie.get_height()+50))
        janela.blit(text,textPos)
    def font2(self):
        font=pygame.font.Font(None,100)
        text=font.render(str(self.pontuacao2),1,(255,255,255))
        textPos=text.get_rect(left=(superficie.get_width()/2-superficie.get_width()/4),y=(superficie.get_height()-superficie.get_height()+50))
        janela.blit(text,textPos)






    def comecar(self):
        self.velocidadeY=8
        self.velocidadeX=5
        bola1.x=superficie.get_width()/2-bolaImagem.get_width()/2
        bola1.y=superficie.get_height()/2-bolaImagem.get_height()/2 
        aleatorio=random.randint(1,4)
        self.ultimaPosX=superficie.get_width()/2-bolaImagem.get_width()/2
        self.ultimaPosY=superficie.get_height()/2-bolaImagem.get_height()/2 
        if aleatorio==1:
            self.mover="subirEsquerda"
        elif aleatorio==2:
            self.mover="subirDireita"
        elif aleatorio==3:
            self.mover="descerDireita"
        elif aleatorio==4:
            self.mover="descerEsquerda"                   
    def continuar(self):
        if self.mover=="subirEsquerda":
            self.subirEsquerda()
        elif self.mover=="subirDireita":
            self.subirDireita()
        elif self.mover=="descerDireita":
            self.descerDireita()
        elif self.mover=="descerEsquerda":
            self.descerEsquerda()            






bola1=bola()
bola1.comecar()


def imprimirBola(x,y):
    janela.blit(bolaImagem,(x,y))



pygame.key.set_repeat(1)


while True:
    clock.tick(60)
    interface()
    bola1.colisao()
    bola1.continuar()
    janela.blit(fundoFinal,(0,0)) 
    imprimirBarra(barra1.x,barra1.y)
    imprimirBarra(barra2.x,barra2.y)
    imprimirBola(bola1.x,bola1.y)
    bola1.font1()
    bola1.font2()


    pygame.display.update()
```

Where I think the problem is (inside method `colisao()` in `class bola()`,where it should check if the ball hits the paddles):

```
        elif self.x<5+barraImagem.get_width()-1 and self.y>self.ultimaPosY and self.y in lista1:
            self.ultimaPosX=self.x
            self.ultimaPosY=self.y
            self.mover="descerDireita" 
        elif self.x<5+barraImagem.get_width()-1 and self.y<self.ultimaPosY and self.y in lista1:
            self.ultimaPosX=self.x
            self.ultimaPosY=self.y
            self.mover="subirDireita" 
        elif self.x>superficie.get_width()-5-barraImagem.get_width()-bolaImagem.get_width()-1 and self.y<self.ultimaPosY and self.y in lista2:
            self.ultimaPosX=self.x
            self.ultimaPosY=self.y
            self.mover="subirEsquerda"
        elif self.x>superficie.get_width()-5-barraImagem.get_width()-bolaImagem.get_width()-1 and self.y>self.ultimaPosY and self.y in lista2:
            self.ultimaPosX=self.x
            self.ultimaPosY=self.y
            self.mover="descerEsquerda"
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but with this much code being posted, the language barrier is made more significant.  If you limited your code to a smaller example that contains your collision logic, it would be much easier to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check if the ball has collided with the paddle why not use the colliderect method?

The code would look something like this:

```
barraImagemRect = barraImagem.get_rect()

bolaImagemRect = bolaImagem.get_rect()
isCollided = bolaImagemRect.colliderect(barraImagemRect)
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

To detect collisions, I've been using:

```
for dot in particles:
             if get_dist(dot.rect,boom.rect)<dot.radius+boom.radius :
                 particles.remove(dot)
```

using defining the radius to show the size, and when the radius connect, it removes the particles(ball). This way, it has a constant detection method to find out if the balls collide.

This will have to be in an always active state and defined at the start of the program.

Note that this doesn't directly cause a collision effect, but it can be easily altered by reversing the speed or doing an instant rotate based on the angle.

Comment: Lack of punctuation makes the text very hard to understand. I hope I got it right.